# Как сохранять файл в определённую папку?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, ос, bs4

***Вопрос 1:***

В коде я пометил строку **"X1"**:

Правильно ли я перехожу в папку? Если нет, то как правильно?

***Вопрос 2:***

В коде я пометил строку **"X2"**:

Правильно ли я перехожу назад? Если нет, то как правильно?

***Вопрос 3:***

Что это за ошибка?

```
File "c:/Users/mr_do/Desktop/parsing/parsing.py", line 55, in get_content_page
    with open(f'{photo_of_goods.get("alt")}.jpeg', 'ab') as file:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Б/у Samsung Белый в Бишкек.jpeg'
```

```
def get_content_page(html):
    data = {}

    os.mkdir('images') # создаю папку 
    for i in html:
        a = get_html(i) # получаю основную страницу
        soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'html.parser')

        photo_of_goods = soup.find('div', class_='left-side-carousel').find('img') # нахожу фото. Далее получаю ссылку на фото ниже

        print(photo_of_goods.get('src')) # для просмотра ссылки

        with open(f'{photo_of_goods.get("alt")}.jpeg', 'ab') as file:
            os.chdir(r'\images') # X1
            file.write(p:=requests.get(photo_of_goods.get('src')).content)

    os.chdir(r'../') # X2
    return photo_of_goods
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Вопрос 1

Нет смысла менять рабочую директорию после открытия файла, т.к. файл открылся уже в **текущей** рабочей директории. Если хотите записать в файл в папке `images`, то делаете так:

```py
with open(f'images/{photo_of_goods.get("alt")}.jpeg', 'ab') as file:
    file.write(p:=requests.get(photo_of_goods.get('src')).content)
```

#### Вопрос 2

Вопрос не актуален, см. ответ на **вопрос 1**.

#### Вопрос 3

Как Вам уже ответили, имя файла не может содержать `/`, т.к. этот символ является разделителем между директориями. В данном случае путь `Б/у Samsung Белый в Бишкек.jpeg` интерпретируется как:

- *папка* `Б`/*файл* `у Samsung Белый в Бишкек.jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

На windows варианты X1 и X2 рабочие. Ошибка в том, что слеш в названии файла.

```
import os
import requests

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(r"..\папка1\папка2") # работает
# os.chdir(r"../папка1/папка2") # работает
os.chdir(r"../")              # работает
print(os.getcwd())
p = requests.get('https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/2/69/san-francisco-california-usa-5825.jpg') # любая картинка
# out = open("Б/у Samsung Белый в Бишкек.jpeg", "wb") # ошибка
out = open("Samsung Белый в Бишкек.jpeg", "wb")      # норм
out.write(p.content)
out.close()
```